# Magento 2 API Get Customer Cart Data using customer ID

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2

I am building custom magento 2 API. I want to get customer **CART DATA** using **CUSTOMER_ID**. I am doing this to serve magento data into android and ios customer devices.

I have tried following code but its not working.

```
$params = $this->request->getPostValue();
$customerId = $params["customer_id"];
        
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

//Code to get customer cart data
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
$customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId); // where `$customerId` is your `customer id`
return $items = $customerQuote->getAllItems();
```

For security concern, I am passing custom permanent token and customer id.

[image]

I have also tried many other sample codes but they are not working anyone can help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are passing customer id into POST method.
Can you try following ?

Add following requirements

```
...
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
...
protected $quoteFactory;
...


 public function __construct(
 ...
 \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
 ...
){
 ...
 $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
 ...
 }
```

try following function

```
public function getCart() {

    $params = $this->request->getPostValue();
    $customerId = $params["customer_id"];
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
    
    $customerFirstName = $customerObj->getFirstname();
    $customerFirstName = $customerObj->getLastname(); 
    
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerObj);
    
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    
    $cart_data = array();
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name'=> $item_data['name'],
            'product_id'=> $item_data['product_id'],
            'price'=>$item_data['price'],                               
            'qty'=> $item_data['qty'],
        );
    } 
    
    return $cart_data;
    
}
```

Comment: just out of interest, why are you using object manager to load the customer object when you're already capable of doing it via dependency injection like you are with quote factory?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use customer token instead of Customer ID, that's how Magento handles customer-related requests. You may retrieve the token when the customer is being signed in.

1. Declare your API endpoint in `Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/example/customer/quote" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\QuoteManagerInterface" method="getQuote"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
</routes>
```

2. Your function would look like that

```
    public function getQuote(int $customerId)
    {
        // Token will be automatically replaced with the Customer ID, so $customerId is an integer here
    }
```

3. API Request would look like that

```
GET: {{host}}example/customer/quote
HEADER: Authorization: Bearer {{customerToken}}
```

curl example

```
curl -sS -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer 99x8vbo999ox5qxjm7uhsso7ny3fzl5o' \
-X GET http://local.magento2.com/rest/default/V1/example/customer/quote
```

It's a more secure way to retrieve customer data. I would not recommend you to pass customer ID via API.

**OR,**

If you want to use admin token, specify customer ID in the declaration of an endpoint. It will be also available as the 1st argument of your function.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/example/customer/quote/:customerId" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\QuoteManagerInterface" method="getQuote"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Vendor_Module::general"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Yes for security concern I am passing custom permanent token with api calls. ie. https://prnt.sc/wfrg73